# Where can I put ads of open source forum on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, advertising

I have searched Stack Overflow but couldn't find where to put ads of my open source forum.

Where can I put ads of open source forum?

Comment: I was not aware that you could put up random ads on this site.

Comment: Or do you mean learning how to put ads on your own site?

Comment: Stackoverflow is NOT a forum.

Comment: Depends: Do you want to advertise your forum, or your forum software?

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising